Pagination breaks JavaScript Event listeners
I am experiencing an issue where the JavaScript event listeners break when navigating through pagination links. After navigating, only the first and last delete buttons retain their event listeners.
I've tried removing the event listeners when clicking on the pagination links and then re-adding them, but it still doesn't work as expected.
Could anyone help me figure this out? Thank you!
document.querySelectorAll('.openModal').forEach(function(button) {
                button.addEventListener('click', function() {
                    document.getElementById('modal').classList.remove('hidden');
                });
            });

<tbody>
    @foreach ($clients as $client)
        <tr class="border-b border-neutral-200">
            <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4">{{ $client->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $client->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $client->inn }}</td>
            <td>
                <button
                class="openModal rounded bg-red-400 px-4 py-2 text-white hover:bg-red-600"
                data-client-id="{{ $client->id }}">Delete</button>
                </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>


I solve the same problem with Livewire hooks, you can try :
Livewire.hook('element.init', ({ component, el }) => {
    
document.querySelectorAll('.openModal').forEach(function(button) {
                button.addEventListener('click', function() {
                    document.getElementById('modal').classList.remove('hidden');
                });
            });
})

You can check this
Github discussion for more information.
